# Way to see the Protocol Witness Tables generated for a conforming type?

Tags: ios, swift, llvm, swift-protocols

I have been wondering if there is a way for us to see and inspect the Protocol Witness Table (PWT) generated for a conforming type in Swift. I am mainly interested in two things:

1. Is a PWT generated for a type?
2. What are the contents of that PWT?

I have been looking for a way but haven't had any luck. Does anyone know of if it is possible?